# Section or group name 'oracle.manageddataaccess.client' is already defined

Tags: oracle

after updating the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess dll from version 4.121.1.0 to version 4.121.2.0, since I could not save values of type CLOB in the previous version using NHibernate, on the client machine it gave this error:
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'OracleInternal.Common.ProviderConfig' threw an exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Section or group name 'oracle.manageddataaccess.client' is already defined. Updates to this may only occur at the configuration level where it is defined.

On my development machine this does not occur, I looked at the machine.config files of his machine and this section is not included, I already tried with and without the settings that Nuget added in the app.config, but nothing seems to work.
Anyone know how I can resolve this?
Thank you

Comment: Same problem here. Even can't work with the solution with visual studio...

Comment: In my case on the client machine in machine.config, I already had a section configured for this dll, the solution was to remove it from the machine.config and use the one from the app.config

Answer (score 13):

Remove the section with oracle.manageddataaccess.client from your machine.config.

The readme from the NuGet Package tells you to do so.

Comment: Some of my hosts have this in machine.config, and some don't.  How can I add the section to override the section in machine.config?

Comment: @BuilderBee I found it in %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\ . If you use a different version, check the corresponding folder.

Comment: @burkay That is the location of the machine.config, but I asked where to find the readme for the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess NuGet package.

Comment: @BuilderBee My bad. It's in the nupkg file. You can download the latest at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/ and open it up with 7zip.

Comment: What if I do not have the privilege to modify machine.config? Maybe it destroys some other application? But I still need another (newer) version?

Answer (score 8):

drop into the app.config and remove or comment this section:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<!-- <configSections>
        <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.18.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
</configSections> -->
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
</startup>
<system.data>
```

Comment: Be careful to comment the `configSections`. There are also usually other sections inside the `configSections` like the `entityFramework` section which would result in errors if commented out. Just comment the `oracle.manageddataaccess.client` section.

Comment: I know this is an old request, but I seem to have the same problem. Are you saying that the oracle.manageddataaccess.client section in the app's config file is mere nonesense, can only do harm (a conflict with other settings on the PC), and is not even needed when a client's PC doesn't happen to have other settings for this (e.g. in a machine.config file)? Is it just a mistake that VisualStudio writes this entry in App.config and it should *always* be removed manually?

Answer (score 3):

I got this same error "The type initializer for 'OracleInternal.Common.ProviderConfig' threw an exception".

When I ran my app, in my Console error messages, "There is a duplicate 'oracle.manageddataaccess.client' section defined."

Turns out the definition for Oracle.ManagedDataAccess was in my WebAPI web.config and also the machine config.

Had to update THIS specific machine.config:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config - do a search on "managed" and comment out in 3 places.

Comment: by removing duplicate entries, the issue dissapears