# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client is already defined - Updates may only occur at the configuration level where it is defined

Tags: c#

I have written an app that uses Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and sent the app (the bin/Debug folder to be precise) to another company. Now, when they start the app they get the following error:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Section or group name 'oracle.manageddataaccess.client' is already defined. Updates to this may only occur at the configuration level where it is defined.

There seems to be something very basic about those NuGet packages or the Oracle package in particular that I do not understand. The Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll is in the folder I sent to the other company. My understanding was that once an appropriate .NET version is installed on their computers, my app must run regardless of what else is installed on the machine. But the error message sounds to me like some other app also works with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and is somehow considered the master for it and doesn't allow my app to run? This must be a misunderstanding on my part, but what what else could that message mean?

Sorry for sounding stupid. I know, it is most likely that I made some mistake myself, for how could Windows allow another app to rule mine? Could someone please explain what the error message means and what I can do to make my app run on any company's computers?

Comment: Sound like a mixup of config files

Comment: Maybe this can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43048353/section-or-group-name-oracle-manageddataaccess-client-is-already-defined

Comment: @vernou: Thank you. I saw this other request, but I don't really understand it. I have sent my complete bin/Debug folder to that company. Do you suppose that this folder contains multiple conflicting config files? There is only one file ending on the .config extension (myapp.exe.config). Where could that other config file be and where could it stem from and how could it have more power, so to say, than my local config file?

Comment: From the answers, it looks like there is a system config file that conflicts with the app config file. Maybe you can try to remove the section to test.

Comment: @vernou: You think I should remove the `section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" ...` from myapp.exe.config? Then why is this line in my config file at all? Is all it can ever do cause trouble? Or is there a reason for it being there? If I remove ths line, this will apply to all companies I am sending my app updates to. My app has run successfully for quite some time. Only that new company is having trouble with it. I want to avoid causing trouble to the companies that are already using it.

Comment: I suggested this for test purpose and confirm the problem's origin.